# Fill missing dates in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I’ve a lot of DataFrames with 2 columns, like this:

|  | Fecha | unidades |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2.0 |
| 84048 | 2020-09-01 | 4.0 |
| 149445 | 2020-10-01 | 11.0 |
| 532541 | 2020-11-01 | 4.0 |
| 660659 | 2020-12-01 | 2.0 |
| 1515682 | 2021-03-01 | 9.0 |
| 1563644 | 2021-04-01 | 2.0 |
| 1759823 | 2021-05-01 | 1.0 |
| 2226586 | 2021-07-01 | 1.0 |

As it can be seen, there are some months that are missing. Missing data depends on the DataFrame, I can have 2 months, 10, 100% complete, only one...I need to complete column "Fecha" with missing months (from 2020-01-01 to 2021-12-01) and when date is added into "Fecha", add "0" value to "unidades" column.

Each element in Fecha Column is a class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

How could I fill the missing dates for each DataFrame??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a date range and use "Fecha" column to `set_index` + `reindex` to add missing months. Then `fillna` + `reset_index` fetches the desired outcome:

```
df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
df = (df.set_index('Fecha')
      .reindex(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2021-12-01', freq='MS'))
      .rename_axis(['Fecha'])
      .fillna(0)
      .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
        Fecha  unidades
0  2020-01-01       2.0
1  2020-02-01       0.0
2  2020-03-01       0.0
3  2020-04-01       0.0
4  2020-05-01       0.0
5  2020-06-01       0.0
6  2020-07-01       0.0
7  2020-08-01       0.0
8  2020-09-01       4.0
9  2020-10-01      11.0
10 2020-11-01       4.0
11 2020-12-01       2.0
12 2021-01-01       0.0
13 2021-02-01       0.0
14 2021-03-01       9.0
15 2021-04-01       2.0
16 2021-05-01       1.0
17 2021-06-01       0.0
18 2021-07-01       1.0
19 2021-08-01       0.0
20 2021-09-01       0.0
21 2021-10-01       0.0
22 2021-11-01       0.0
23 2021-12-01       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pyjanitor's](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
# create new variable containing all possible dates
fecha={"Fecha":pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2021-12-01', freq='MS')}
df.complete(fecha, fill_value=0) 
        Fecha  unidades
0  2020-01-01         2
1  2020-02-01         0
2  2020-03-01         0
3  2020-04-01         0
4  2020-05-01         0
5  2020-06-01         0
6  2020-07-01         0
7  2020-08-01         0
8  2020-09-01         4
9  2020-10-01        11
10 2020-11-01         4
11 2020-12-01         2
12 2021-01-01         0
13 2021-02-01         0
14 2021-03-01         9
15 2021-04-01         2
16 2021-05-01         1
17 2021-06-01         0
18 2021-07-01         1
19 2021-08-01         0
20 2021-09-01         0
21 2021-10-01         0
22 2021-11-01         0
23 2021-12-01         0
```